# Updating table based on lookup in TALEND

Tags: talend

I have a table (table 1), which I need to join (I am using lookup) with another table (table 2) and update table1 based on changes on table2 using join in tMap:

```
tMysqlInput (table 1) >> lookup with  tMysqlInput (table 2) >> tMap >> tMysqlOutput (table1)
```

Basically updating table1 based on record on changes in table 2 for matching rows.

Please help if any work around.

Comment: You have a solution right there, is it not working ?

Comment: Now it's working,There was a mapping issue in the tmap, as weel as filter issue. Anyway thanks a lot @iMezouar